# Which to use--COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, or SUMPRODUCT?

Tags: excel-formula

I am tracking trouble ticket survey responses. I want to count the number of ticket id's (INC0....) where the ratings for any of the four survey questions associated with that singular trouble ticket are <=6. I need to do this across multiple worksheets and multiple columns.

Example:[example worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9v5d.png)

```
WorkSheet1

Column I = ticket number (INC0001234, INC0001235, etc.)

Column Q = Customer's rating for 1st survey question

Column S = Customer's rating for 2nd survey question

Column U = Customer's rating for 3rd survey question

Column W = Customer's rating for 4th survey question
```

The same exists for all other worksheets (WorkSheet2, WorkSheet3, etc.)

I have found a formula that will work only if I count against one worksheet and/or column.

Example: `=COUNTIFS('WorkSheet1'!$I:$I,"INC0*",'WorkSheet1'!$Q:$Q,"<=6")`

This formula I tried but doesn't work:

```
=COUNTIFS('WorkSheet1'!$I:$I,"INC0*",'WorkSheet1'!$Q:$Q,"<=6",'WorkSheet1'!$S:$S,"<=6", 'WorkSheet1'!$U:$U,"<=6",'WorkSheet1'!$W:$W,"<=6")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear why at the end of your example your WorkSheet1/Column I contains the number to be sumed when your example puts the Ticket number in column I.
In any case, you can't do it in one single cell. You will need at least one helper column. In column X, input :

```
=IF(MIN(Q1:W1)<=6,SUM(Q1:W1),0)
```

This will give you the sum of all ratings on the line if one of them is 6 or lower. You can then sum column X to get your total rating sum, wich looks like what your trying to get by summing your column I at the end of your question.

Your Countifs formula doesn't get you what you want because it is looking for a line meeting all criterias (e.g. all 4 ratings must be below or equal to 6) and will return the number of occurences where this happens. Sumifs would have gotten you closer, but again, it would have check when multiple criteria are met and then sum a range when this happens. Sumproduct is not well adapted to this circumstance where you have to sum all cells based on the individual content of any cell in the range.

Comment: Pomul. I updated my original question. I mistakenly added the part about adding values that would total out to 71. What I am really after is a formula that counts column I (ticket number) if either columns Q, S, U or W contains a number <=6. Additionally, I want to do this across several worksheets.  I added a picture to my original question above for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If all the ticket id's in rows are unique, you can use just, formula in column Y, =Countif(Q2:W2,"<=6") and drag it down.